# Autolayout problems in bigger devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-autolayout

I am developing an iPhone app in which, i have made this page using autolayout

but it shows unwanted spaces above **Register Me**(yellow button) in bigger iPhones

Constraints given are:
top,bottom, leading and trailing with respect to its subviews to all the controls. (there is no warning or misplaced constraints i see in xcode)

Here is the screenshot of iPhone 4s
[image]

Here is the screenshot of iPhone 6+
[image]

I want to minimize the empty spacing in bigger iPhones... 
How do i solve this problem?

***Please help and thanks in advance***

Comment: That is a design problem without generic answer. It is something *you* have to decide about - *you* have to define what you want.

Comment: **Constraints given are: top,bottom, leading and trailing with respect to its subviews to all the controls.** if you give button's bottom  it will create issues so **register me** button constraint should be top (YOU WILLREGISTER's BOTTOM) , leading , Trailing and height

Comment: if you want all thing in center like iphone 4 screen other solution can be you can put all in a view align vertically, horizontally center with supverview will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

If your intent to target iOS 9 users, you should use [UIStackView](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUu9e94eXMAhVCnJQKHfRoD-cQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FUIKit%2FReference%2FUIStackView_Class_Reference%2F&usg=AFQjCNEdbrW1dDbd2mkOnd2gyvLvxv_5NQ&sig2=HzeDpOJt_Dgi_KFy2Rpe0Q), the provide a lot of flexibility in terms of alignment and distribution. 
If not, then you or your design team has to find a solution.

Comment: My app also supports iOS 7, Stackview is available after iOS 9 :(

Comment: Ok. So now for "I want to minimize the empty spacing in bigger iPhones" there could be lots of answers. Put it in a view align it in horizontal centre. Put everything in scrollview etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a suggestion for you.  You have roughly seven regions of interest there.  First one is the title 'Register Kano .. ' etc.  Then there are 5 text entry areas - name, email, password, etc.  Finally you have 3 small lines of info text - I would count this as one final area, so 7 in all.

What I would do is create 7 parent UIViews to put that stuff in.  I would give them 'equal height' constraints, and make them sit above and below each other with no gap.  Then as the iphone screen changes height, those areas stretch out height-wise to fill the area.  Heres a rough mockup :

[image: 7 equally sized parent UIViews to put your stuff in]

Select all those UIViews and select the 'equal heights' constraint :

[image: Equal Heights (note the tick)]

Then every view except the bottom one needs these constraints (top, leading trailing to superview 0px)

[image: Top, leading and trailing]

Then your bottom view needs those plus 'bottom' too :

[image: Same but adhere to bottom too]

So all that remains to do is to put your content in each of those boxes, but centre them in terms of vertical position relative to their superview.

Comment: You can simply do this using aspect ration constraint instead of putting each   component in various container views.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the margin contraints of your controls on big devices.
This would add space between each rows on big screens, will looks better as you ask.

Something like :

```
myControl.heightConstraint.constant += 20.0f
```

This is how I would do, but you have to decide how you update your layout for big devices

Comment: How do i add this kind of constraint in storyboard for bigger iPhones only?

Comment: You have two options : 
1) Programmaticaly
2) By using the SizeClass to set updated contraint only for certain sizes

Answer (score 0):

@Krunal you can use the size class and set the constraints accordingly so it will give a brief idea how to fit the UI design for every device!!

Answer (score 0):

you can set constraints relative to height of your base view. This will make your interface objects evenly distributed over layout. Lets assume you have 8 regions. for `registerLabel`

```
registerLabel.leading = baseView.leading
registerLabel.trailing = baseView.trailing
registerLabel.top     = baseView.top
registerLabel.bottom  = baseView.bottom * (1/8)// it will be always proportional to height of view
```

then for icons at the beginning `firstIcon`

```
firstIcon.leading = baseView.leading + 10
firstIcon.height  = firstIcon.width
firstIcon.height  = baseView.height*(1/9)// to give a gap between icons
firstIcon.bottom  = baseView.bottom * (2/8)
```

and then you can set textfield's constraints according to `firstIcon`

for other icons you can go on with 3/8, 4/8, 5/8, 6/8 and set the relative textfields constraints according to that icon.

and lastly for `registerMe` button

```
registerButton.leading  = baseView.leading
registerButton.trailing = baseView.trailing
registerButton.bottom   = baseView.bottom
registerLabel.height    = baseView.height * (1/8)
```

With this approach your icons size also decrease and increase relatively with height of view and all the page will be filled.

`baseView` is view of controller.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here, you kept the width according to superview ie phone width, but your height is fixed.

Do one thing instead of giving Height constraint, use aspect ration in combination with leading , trailing and top constraint. When view will stretch widthwise , your component's height will also Increase and fill the extra space for iphone 6.

This is the best thing you can do keeping the same layout and design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have given some fixed height in views.

As every element is depends on it above and below elements constraints, this might be possible of empty space.

So try to divide the View part then the dependency of constraints will reduce.

If you don't want to show empty space, then use center horizontally to one of the element which will look good, here it may be the third field.

Then start giving same constraints to Register button. Sure it will help you in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hey its the best solution for you is stackView 
Combine your objects in single stackView.
You can combine your object vertically and also horizontally.
It will decrease your space and view will arranged in awesome manner.
You can select your objects like this.[image: selected image]
Click here to make it stack.
[image: stack button]
Now you can reduce your space like this.